# Failing to pass unknown headers through nginx

Tags: nginx

I need to add some custom headers into a request that gets sent through an NGINX to a reverse proxy. Unfortunately, the "outer" nginx, sitting on the EC2 instance where the docker network of the application is sat, appears to be not passing the extra headers we've added.

So two questions:

Practically how do I log this -- check the docs and can't see how to log all headers for an incoming request as it seems to be doing known headers only.

How do I pass through the "new" or "unknown" headers?

Comment: Nginx should not be filtering headers based on whether they are *new* or *unknown*. However, it will filter [invalid header names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#ignore_invalid_headers). What naming format do you use?

Comment: This looks like it was the problem for us -- thanks. Not something I was aware of, but we had underscores in the header names. I'll fix that and then if it works put your comment as an answer.